# Java RMI server: Running servers with different data

Tags: java, class, sockets, server, rmi

I have a question about running multiple servers in JAVA RMI programming.

I should have 3 servers with the same functionality and different data in their hashmaps.

So my question is, could I create one class for servers and run multiple times, or create 3 different classes for servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could I create one class for servers and run multiple times

Yes. Just supply the different `HashMap` data in the constructor.

You'll have to register all three instances in the Registry, under different names, or make them accessible via some other RMI mechanism.

Contrary to @JunedAhsan's answer, they can all share the same TCP port, and by default they will, if they're all exported from the same JVM, and there's no reason not to do that.

Comment: but I don't know how to run multiple instances.

Comment: Just create them with `new`, and export them if the class doesn't extend `UnicastRemoteObject.`

Comment: thanks for immediate response. how to initiate different hashmaps? in which constructor you mean?

Comment: Come off it. What do you mean 'which constructor'? How can I comment on code you haven't posted?